# Replace mvc client-side validation with other framework than jquery validate

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, jquery-validate

I want to know **if** and **how** it is possible to use an other client-side validation framework (than jquery validate, eg. Parsley) in asp.net mvc?

I just looked into the mvc sourcecode and it seems to be hard-wired.
This [class](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/e985fa5d423968f36a651a354d9c953192c52532/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Rendering/UnobtrusiveValidationAttributesGenerator.cs) creates the attributes, which will be added to the control later.

Maybe there is a way to inherit from a class and configure it somehow to be used as default. It seems that asp.net mvc have too many static classes (e.g. HtmlHelper) which makes it nearly impossible to extend some functionality without rewriting a lot of framework-code?

The power of common data annotations is cool to descibe meta information about the data. It's used by Entity Framework and MVC,
but the client-side validation should be limited to jquery validate?

I know, that I can configure client-validation frameworks like parsley to get used with an other prefix like the "data-val-" (of jquery validate) instead of "data-parsley-", but not all features can be used this way and conflicts are possible.

Hope anyone have an answer for me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use any client side validation you want to use. Asp.net provides server code that is translated into client code but that's not the only option. You can use any client side code you want independent of the server code framework. Just include the appropriate client side code on the pages you wish and it'll work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But I want to use the existing framework, so that the data annotations will be used and the htmlhelper e.g. @Html.EditorFor ... Code will automatically use them and call my custom code to handle the property attributes.

Normally mvc renders the jquery attributes to the control automatically, but I hope, that there is a possibility to hook my code there.

Comment: I think you're going to have to rewrite the framework code if you want that.